# How do I properly implement a property in F#?

Tags: f#, mutable, let-binding

Consider my first attempt, a simple type in F# like the following:

```
type Test() =
    inherit BaseImplementingNotifyPropertyChangedViaOnPropertyChanged()
    let mutable prop: string = null
    member this.Prop
        with public get() = prop
        and public set value =
            match value with
                | _ when value = prop -> ()
                | _ -> 
                    let prop = value
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Prop")
```

Now I test this via C# (this object is being exposed to a C# project, so apparent C# semantics are desirable):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TaskMaster_Test()
{
    var target = new FTest();
    string propName = null;
    target.PropertyChanged += (s, a) => propName = a.PropertyName;
    target.Prop = "newString";

    Assert.AreEqual("Prop", propName);
    Assert.AreEqual("newString", target.Prop);

    return;
}
```

`propName` is properly assigned, my F# Setter is running, but the second assert is failing because the underlying value of `prop` isn't changed.  This sort of makes sense to me, because if I remove `mutable` from the `prop` field, no error is generated (and one should be because I'm trying to mutate the value).  I think I must be missing a fundamental concept.

What's the correct way to rebind/mutate `prop` in the `Test` class so that I can pass my unit test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
type Test() =
    inherit BaseImplementingNotifyPropertyChangedViaOnPropertyChanged()
    let mutable prop: string = null
    member this.Prop
        with public get() = prop
        and public set value =
            match value with
                | _ when value = prop -> ()
                | _ -> 
                    prop <- value
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Prop")
```

You need to make the binding mutable and then alter its value in your setter.  In your initial code, you were just creating a new binding (also called `prop`) within your setter, so no change was visible.

Comment: Thanks, @kvb.  Nothing makes me feel like a n00b at the language than a fix as simple as that.  :)

Comment: @Greg - no problem.  The way that bindings and shadowing work can take a bit of getting used to, particularly since other languages do things so differently.  However, once you get your mental model straight, I think the elegance of F#'s approach becomes apparent.

Answer (score 9):

As a side-note, I would probably use `if .. then` instead of the `match` construct as it makes the code more succinct (patterh matching is especially valuable when you need to test the value agains multiple complex patterns). Also, `public` is the default access for `member`, so you can make the code a bit more succinct:

```
type Test() = 
    inherit BaseImplementingNotifyPropertyChangedViaOnPropertyChanged() 
    let mutable prop : string = null 
    member this.Prop 
        with get() = prop 
        and set(value) = 
            if value <> prop then 
               prop <- value 
               this.OnPropertyChanged("Prop")
```

Comment: I totally already bought your book.  :)  Useful reading, though I wish I'd kept it handy when I asked this question!

Answer (score 5):

In your pattern match you are actually binding a new value with

```
let prop = value
```

When you bind a value like this with the same name, it will shadow the other value for the scope of the newly declared one. I believe what you actually want to do is this:

```
prop <- value
```